# The server side of GWT application

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to write a server side of GWT application in other languages then Java if yes how to use GWT-RPC mechanism, an sample code please

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please read the GWT documentation [Communication with the Server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html):

> If you can run Java on the backend and are creating an interface for your application's server-side business logic, GWT RPC is probably your best choice. [...]
>
> If your application talks to a server that cannot host Java servlets, or one that already uses another data format like JSON or XML, you can make HTTP requests to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your server in any language you choose, GWT is just JavaScript to be run in your users' browsers.

If you decide to go that route, you should look into using [`RequestFactory`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) to communicate with your server instead of GWT-RPC, which is Java-specific. RequestFactory uses standard JSON, which any language can read/write.

Comment: GWT-RPC is not Java-specific, but I agree that RequestFactory is the way to go. Also, with GWT 2.3, RequestFactory can be used to consume JsonRpc services, which makes even easier to interface with non-Java backends.

Comment: @Thomas You're right, GWT-RPC is not technically "Java-specific" -- what it is is an intentionally opaque format that doesn't have an implementation in anything besides Java. So until someone reverse engineers it (and maintains it), you're stuck with Java on the server. Or just use RequestFactory.

Comment: I mostly agree. Except that there have been implementations of GWT-RPC in non-Java languages (PHP and Python at least), unfortunately not maintained (as you said); and RequestFactory might well be JSON but it's still some kind of "JSON-based protocol" (unless you use the JsonRpc support in GWt 2.3) that no one has implemented in non-Java, as far as I can tell, so "until someone reverse engineers it (and maintais it)", you're stuck with Java on the server" or JsonRpc (which has limitations: one method call only per `fire()` for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Dont waist your time with GWT-RPC. It's bad. Use RequestFactory. I am surprised people are promoting GWT-RPC. It's a broken toy.